# Prove: $\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} (g+f)(x) \ dx = \int\limits_a^b {{f(x)}dx}+ \overline{\int_{a}^{b}} g(x) \ dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, supremum-and-infimum, riemann-integration, integral-inequality

I am trying to prove the following theorem:

> let $f:\mathbb [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be a Riemann integrable function, and let $g:\mathbb [a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be a bounded function.
>
> Prove that:
> $$\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} (g+f)(x) \ dx = \int_a^b {{f(x)}dx}+ \overline{\int_{a}^{b}} g(x) \ dx$$

When we define:

> Let  $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be a function and let $P=\{a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b\}$ be an arbitrary partition of $[a,b]$.
> $$\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \ dx:=\inf_{P}U(f,P)$$
> $$\underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \ dx:=\sup_{P}L(f,P)$$
> When $U(f,P)$ is the upper Darboux sum and $L(f,P)$ is the lower Darboux sum, with respect to the partition P.

#### my try:

1. I have managed to prove that:
   $$\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} (g+f)(x) \ dx \le \overline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \ dx+  \overline{\int_{a}^{b}} g(x) \ dx $$
2. Now I am trying to show that:
   $$\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} (g+f)(x) \ dx \ge \underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f \ dx + \overline{\int_{a}^{b}} g(x) \ dx$$

and then by using the fact that:
$$ \overline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \ dx = \underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \ dx \tag{*}$$

we get what we need.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to prove the second identity. I tried to play (without success) with the $L(P)$ and $U(P)$ sums and with $\sup$ and $\inf$ properties to get the result.

**Any hints what to do from here?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd guess that in both in 1 and 2 you want to have "+" between the two integrals?

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of the notation: $\overline{\int_{a}^{b}}$?

Comment: @user: the notation refers to limit of upper Darboux sums. There is a similar notation for limit of lower Darboux sums with bar below the integral sign.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you. I hoped it will be clarified in the body of the question.

Comment: @user : I hope the question is updated by the asker with this information.

Comment: @user@ParamanandSingh The question was updated with the required clarification.

Comment: Probably you need still to mention what are the $U(f,P)$ and $L(f,P)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to show that$\newcommand{\dd}{\; \mathrm{d}}\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}$
$$\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} (g+f)(x) \dd x \ge \underline{\int\limits_a^b} {{f(x)}\dd x} + \overline{\int_{a}^{b}} g(x) \dd x.$$
The question did not specify the definition of the upper/lower integral, I will assume that we're using

\begin{align*}
\overline{\int\limits_a^b} f(x) \dd x &= \inf_P U(f,P)\\
\underline{\int\limits_a^b} f(x) \dd x &= \sup_P L(f,P)
\end{align*}

as in the Wikipedia article on [Darboux integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral).

Now it suffices to notice that
\begin{align*}
U(f+g,P)
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} \sup_{t\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}(f(t)+g(t)) (x_{i+1}-x_i)\\
&\ge\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} \left(\inf_{t\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(t) + \sup_{t\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}g(t)\right) (x_{i+1}-x_i)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} \inf_{t\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f(t) (x_{i+1}-x_i)+ \sum_{i=0}^{n+1}\sup_{t\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]}g(t) (x_{i+1}-x_i)\\
&=L(f,P)+U(g,P).
\end{align*}

Now let $\ve>0$ be arbitrary.
Since the lower integral is supremum of the values $L(f,P)$, there exists a partition $P_1$ such that
$$L(f,P_1)\ge\underline{\int\limits_a^b} {{f(x)}dx}-\ve.$$

The same inequality is true for every partition $P$ which is finer<sup>1</sup> than $P_1$. For any such partition we get
$$U(f+g,P) \ge U(g,P) + \underline{\int\limits_a^b} {{f(x)}dx} -\ve$$
and applying infimum to both sides we get
$$\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} (g+f)(x) \dd x \ge \underline{\int\limits_a^b} {{f(x)}\dd x} + \overline{\int_{a}^{b}} g(x) \dd x-\ve.$$
Using the fact that the above is true for every $\ve>0$, we get the desired inequality
$$\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} (g+f)(x) \dd x \ge \underline{\int\limits_a^b} {{f(x)}\dd x} + \overline{\int_{a}^{b}} g(x) \dd x.$$

---

<sup>1</sup>If partition $P'$ is finer than the partition $P$, then we get
\begin{align*}
U(f,P')&\le U(f,P)\\
L(f,P')&\ge L(f,P)
\end{align*}
See: [Let $P'$ be a refinement of the partition $P$, then $s(f,P) \leq s(f,P') \leq S(f,P') \leq S(f,P)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2629517), [Proving the more partition points the smaller the Darboux integral gets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/373285).

<sup>2</sup>In fact, we have taken only infimum over the partitions finer than $P_1$ rather than the infimum over all partitions. But this gives the same result> If $P$ is any partition and $P'$ is a refinement of both $P$ and $P_1$, then we have $U(f,P')\le U(f,P)$. This implies that
$$\inf\{U(f,P'); P'\text{ is a partition finer than }P_1\} \le \inf\{U(f,P); P'\text{ is a partition}\}.$$

---

It is not the same question, but this inequality is mentioned also in the answer to this question: [Additivity of definite integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1708128). The question can be found both [using Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24U(f%2Bg%2CP)%5Cge%20L(f%2CP)%2BU(g%2CP)%24&p=1) and [using SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%7B87af4fb4-f382-4019-8dfd-5a9a98867f5a%7D).

---

This might remind you of the proof of [similar inequalities for limit superior and limit inferior of sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70478/properties-of-liminf-and-limsup-of-sum-of-sequences-limsup-s-n-limin). Indeed, with some effort we could show that the upper and lower integral can be defined as a limit superior/inferior of some net. The notion of a net is a generalization of a sequence - you could encounter such notion typically in some course on general topology. (Some references where one could find more about limit superior and limit inferior of a net are given in the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/about-the-notion-of-limsup-and-liminf), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188722/limsups-of-nets) and also in the [Wikipedia article on nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29#Limit_superior) - I will add also a link [to the current revisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Net_(mathematics)&oldid=1013106338#Limit_superior).)

But even if we do not want to use nets - after all, learning about them and showing the equivalence would be non-trivial efforts - it is still useful to keep in mind that there is some kind of analogy between these two notions, so at least sometime we could expect to use somewhat similar arguments in the proofs.

Comment: It might be worth explaining why $\overline{\int_a^b} g(x) \ dx$ is the limit of $U(g,P)$ as the norm of $P$ converges to zero. Indeed, the definition of $\overline{\int_a^b} g(x) \ dx$ is just as the infimum of $U(g,P)$ over all $P$. It is not immediately obvious you can get close to the infimum just by taking sufficiently fine $P$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I have edited the post to use the definition using supremum and infimum.

Comment: How do you get the last inequality?   You state correctly that the lower integral of $f$ is the supremum over lower sums.  Hence, for every $P$ we have $L(f,P) \leqslant \underline{\int\limits_a^b} {{f(x)}dx}$.  You also showed $L(f,P) \leqslant U(f+g,P) - U(g,P)$ -- where the same partition appears on both sides.  How then does it follow that $\underline{\int\limits_a^b} {{f(x)}dx} \leqslant  U(f+g,P) - U(g,P)$?

Comment: I can only see $ \underline{\int\limits_a^b} {{f(x)}dx}=\sup_P L(f,P) \leqslant \sup_P[U(f+g,P) - U(g,P)]$ which is not helpful.

Comment: For the record, the previous two comments refer to [this revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4109378/5). @RRL Thanks for you comment. That was quite an embarrassing mistake on my side.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Very well done.